# Wordpress Post Content Get Url

Tags: wordpress, url, post

quick question I know in wordpress you can get post_content,etc
but let say I input into the content just a url such http://www.google.com and then
i want to get that url inside a div so it would look like  something along those lines. do I have to do anything special with the url or can i simply just do get post_content.
My end goal is to incorporate the url in a colorbox so it will just grab the url from the post content and use it with the colorbox??

hope that made some sense...
thank you
-david

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. Can you clarify? This is how I read it. You have a post. The post contains a link. You are getting the post content with get_post_content. You want to do something with this content. You are worried about the link for what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to do anything special in terms of preparing your post on the admin side, but to incorporate this into the Colorbox code, make sure you are putting the 'post_content' in the right place. In the 'Outside HTML (IFrame)' example from the Colorbox site:
http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

You could implement your code as follows:

```
<?php your wordpress query here?>
 <a class="colorboxClass" href="<?php the_content(); ?>">Your Colorbox Link Text</a>
<?php end your query?>
```